# SQL query sentence

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm working on a C# project with some data bases. I'm getting an error when executing the following function:

```
//Returns true if the username and password are correct. Otherwise it returns false.
    public bool LogInto(string name, string pass, OleDbConnection cnx)
    {
        DataTable res = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT User,Password FROM UserPassword WHERE (User='"+name+"' AND Password='"+pass+"')", cnx);
        adp.Fill(res);
        bool found = false;
        String user = Convert.ToString(res.Rows[0]["User"]);
        String password = Convert.ToString(res.Rows[0]["Password"]);
        if (name==user && pass==password)
            found = true;
        return found;
    }
```

So this is the full function, however I'm getting an error, I just replaced && with AND. But it still doesn't work. I'm getting ("There was an error parsing the query. // Token number, token line offset, token in error.

What's wrong with it? I had the same function but instead of taking just one row from the data table, it took the whole table and with a loop it looked the row we were looking for. However, I'm trying to do this one, just taking the row we need, because it is more efficient.

Could you guys help me? I can't find my mistake. 
Thank you so much

Comment: What error you get? Can you please show full code? AFAIK, `WHERE` clause doesn't have `&&`. You mean `AND` instead? You should always use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. And don't store your passwords as a plain text.

Comment: You have a severe [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-injection/info) issue here. Use query parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues with the query:

- The and operator in SQL is `and`, not `&&`
- The query is **WIDE OPEN FOR [SQL INJECTION](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) ATTACKS**. You have to escape the strings to be correctly interpreted as string literals.

You can do it like this:

```
string query =
  "SELECT User, Password FROM UserPassword WHERE Username = '" +
  name.Replace("\\", "\\\\").Replace("'", "\\'") +
  "' and Password = '" +
  pass.Replace("\\", "\\\\").Replace("'", "\\'") +
  "'";
```

Note: This way to escape the strings is specific to MySQL. Each database have a different set of characters that needs to be escaped, and in different ways.

If possible you should use a parameterised query instead of concatenating string into the query. That makes it easier to get it correct.

Comment: Thank you sir, I'm going to try it. I did not understand why Password need to be around square brackets though. Thanks! @Guffa

Comment: @user3780731: Actually, that was incorrect. Password is a reserved keyword in some databases, but not in MySQL. Also MySQL uses backticks instead of square brackets to specify identifiers, for when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

First please use parameterized one like this, with IDisposable inherited

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = @""SELECT up.User, up.Password FROM dbo.UserPassword up WHERE up.Username = @Param1" AND Password = @Param2;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param1", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = 'ABC';
    .............
}
```

second try to encrypt it or hash it, there are lot of information about hashing and encrytion on web